# How can something appear on the close queue without a selected reason?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

I was just reviewing the close queue on Electrical Engineering and came across the following question in the close votes queue:

[How to convert a PNG file in to a matrix of pixels?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/148741/how-to-convert-a-png-file-in-to-a-matrix-of-pixels)

It didn't have an actual close vote which is probably because the person who left the following comment doesn't have enough rep to vote to close:

> This should not be in EE SE because it doesn't have much to do with electronics, per se. I think it would be better off in SO

While I agreed it was off-topic (although not necessarily a good question for SO) when performing the review there wasn't any pre-defined reason, I was fairly sure that normally happens for flags to close? It did say off-topic at the top of the window but none of the pre-defined reasons were selected.

I know from other sites you don't get the option to flag with a custom reason so I wondered how it ended up in that state? Also EE.SE no longer has a direct migration path to SO so that option couldn't have been a flag option.

Comment: As far as I know, this happens when a flag is used and not a close vote.

Comment: Probably close although from memory "not a real question" was the final close reason, whereas off-topic has further categories below it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard are you sure that is still the current design?  I thought that the flagged reasons started to appear in the dialog after the Close-Reason refactoring of 2013.

Comment: @psubsee2003 quite sure, yes. The reasons do appear but without any number next to them if it's only a flag.

Answer (score 0):

Either the closevoter retracted his/her vote or (s)he was flagging. In both cases you won't see any option selected, unless someone already reviewed and voted to close.

> I know from other sites you don't get the option to flag with a custom reason so I wondered how it ended up in that state?

If the user which action pushed the q in the review queue wasn't a closevoter, couldn't (s)he just add own comment?